# Not able to login in server via sshpass and attach to a tmux session through bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tmux

I am trying to login in the remote server and attach to a tmux session which is already running in server via script but it always show me:

```
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@host "tmux new-session -d -s my_session 'sudo tailf /opt/log/debug.log';tmux attach -t my_session"
```

Anyone please help me how to open any running file automatically after login because through this method it automatically logs out from remote server.

Comment: add `-tt` to flags for `ssh`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.